# Como pego a data do Calendário no Android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho isso dentro do `onCreate`:

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel(myCalendar);

        }

    };

    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(AgendamentoActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

        }
    });
```

E isso fora:

```
private void updateLabel(Calendar myCalendar) {
    String dia = myCalendar.toString();
    Log.d("TAG", "DATA " + dia);
}
```

E esse Log me retorna:
[image: print]

Como pego a data selecionada de dentro da variável dia?

Comment: Você quer a data completa (objeto Date) ou o dia?

Comment: Gostaria de dd/mm/YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria interessante primeiro formatar a data recebida. Para isso você pode usar o a classe `SimpleDateFormat` usando o método `getTime` do seu calendário. Veja:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String time = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

Adaptando ao seu código, seu método deve ficar desta forma abaixo:

```
private void updateLabel(Calendar myCalendar) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dia = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
    Log.d("TAG", "DATA " + dia);
}
```

Comment: Certo, vou tentar

Comment: Deu erro no:
"Process: com.example.gustavo.domanda, PID: 32438
                                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat;
                                                                                 at com.example.gustavo.domanda.AgendamentoActivity.onCreate(AgendamentoActivity.java:138)"

Comment: A primeira parte do código fica dentro ou fora do onCreate? Pois coloquei dentro.

Comment: Já adaptei ao seu código na ultima parte. O que você não entendeu?!

Comment: Ta, deu certo... O import que eu estava fazendo é que era o errado.
Eu estava com esse: import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat; sendo que o certo era esse:
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;